# Help with SOQL Query

Tags: soql

I have a custom object `Contract__c`, which is in a relationship with `Address__c`. A Contract can have many Addresses, so Adress__c has a lookup field to Contract__c.

I am trying to query all the Addresses related to a contract, but I seem to be having difficulties:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Address__c) FROM Contract__c
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go by the relationship which is likely:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Address__r) FROM Contract__c
```

In order to find the correct relationship name you can look here: [How to find out relationships for SOQL queries?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4737/how-to-find-out-relationships-for-soql-queries)

EDIT: Expand your project and its on the bottom of Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I just realised why it doesn't work It is because Address_c is a junction object. Does that make a difference? I tried appending __r, and it didn't work.

Comment: It's not necessarily just __r.  You'll need to review the lookup field for the relationship name.  In addition, based on which 'direction' you you plan to query, the Parent w/ Child query and the Children w/ Parent queries are written significantly different. THIS is your friend http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: Thanks for that link! I have installed the Eclipse IDE, but can't quite find out how to access this schema thingy. How can I open it?

Comment: @Lily Edited with a screenshot showing where the schema is.

Answer (score 1):

In [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)
For parent-to-child relationships, the parent object has a name for the child relationship that is unique to the parent, the **plural** of the child object name.

In your case, the query should be:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Addresses__r) FROM Contract__c
```

Let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

`Address__r` is the relationship name of the `Address__c` to `Contract__c`

`newAddress` is holding all the value of `Address__c` from `trigger.new`,    So if you have a list of Address then you can use that List of Address instead of `newAddress` this query will return the Contract related to all Addresses

```
List<Contract__c> conList = [Select Id,(Select Id from Address__r) from Contract__c where Id IN (Select Address__c from Address__c where Id IN :newAddress)];
```

If you want to query for single address then simply write the condition for the address in where Clause like:

```
List<Contract__c> conList = [Select Id,(Select Id from Address__r) from Contract__c where Id IN (Select Address__c from Address__c where Id = '0092813000vzvu1')];
```